# Getting mysql result into a jquery array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I am trying to get this array as a result of mysql result.

```
var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
```

Is it as simple as:

```
var availableTags [] = <php echo $result['availabletags']; ?> ;
```

Or should I do something else?

Comment: Your question is missing some information

Comment: It depends upon what your query returns. If it is giving array of objects then you have to change your code.

Comment: What format is `$result['availabletags']` in? Assuming you can create a PHP array from it, then you can do: `var availableTags = <php echo json_encode($result['availabletags']); ?>;`

Answer (score 1):

You can get your result by run of following query :

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)){
    $new_array[] = $row; // Inside while loop
}
```

Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: I am trying to make this code work with mysql result as autocomplete options. http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: What is the easiest way?